# stub commandline result in rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, command-line, rspec, keychain

I have never used ruby and rspec before.

I wrote a couple lines of code where the user can delete keychain from their macs.

```
    elsif params[:name]
  # get default keychains list
  default_path = Fastlane::Actions.sh("security list-keychains", log: false).split

  # iterate to find any of the items in the list matches with parameter name
  does_keychain_exists = true
  default_path.each do |path_to_keychain|
    # sometimes keychain saved as name.keychain-db, check that case too
    if path_to_keychain.include?(params[:name]) == true || path_to_keychain.include?("#{params[:name]}-db") == true
      keychain_path = FastlaneCore::Helper.keychain_path(params[:name])
      if File.exist?(keychain_path)
        complete_delete(original, keychain_path)
      else
        does_keychain_exists = false
      end
    else
      does_keychain_exists = false
    end
  end
```

The code works fine, but I need to add unittest with rspec.

How do I stub  `default_path = Fastlane::Actions.sh("security list-keychains", log: false).split` so default_path variable gets something like

`~/Library/Keychains/test.keychain` or `user/username/Library/Keychains/test.keychain`

the unit test I am trying to edit is:

```
  describe Fastlane do
  describe Fastlane::FastFile do
    describe "Delete keychain Integration" do
      before :each do
        allow(File).to receive(:file?).and_return(false)
      end

      it "works with keychain name found locally" do
        allow(FastlaneCore::FastlaneFolder).to receive(:path).and_return(nil)
        keychain = File.expand_path('test.keychain')
        allow(File).to receive(:file?).and_return(false)
        allow(File).to receive(:file?).with(keychain).and_return(true)

        result = Fastlane::FastFile.new.parse("lane :test do
          delete_keychain ({
            name: 'test.keychain',
            throw_error:false
          })
        end").runner.execute(:test)

        expect(result).to eq("security delete-keychain #{keychain}")
      end
```

Comment: `Fastlane::Actions.expects(:sh).with("security list-keychains", log: false).returns("~/Library/Keychains/test.keychain user/username/Library/Keychains/test.keychain")` does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
keychains = double("keychains")
allow(keychains).to receive(:split).and_return(["~/Library/Keychains/test.keychain", "user/username/Library/Keychains/test.keychain"]
allow(Fastlane::Actions).to receive(:sh).with("security list-keychains", log: false)).and_return(keychains)
```